# connecting to aws elastic search with nodejs aws sdk

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-elasticsearch

what is the best approach in using aws elastic search with nodejs? I am using aws ecs ec2 instance for running my docker containers and is using  the IAM role to accessing the other aws resource like S3 bucket and dynamodb from nodejs.

Can we use the same procedure for accessing the aws elastic search endpoint too?

I added an inline policy with the existing role and added the elastic search end point arn. but the nodejs sdk is not able to connect to the ES. when the aws key and id is added as environment variable in task definition it starts working. But I dont need to use that method as it will conflict with the other aws resource. (looks like the dev team is configured the program such that it looks for env)

Answer (score 0):

It for sure is not the best method but you can also use a ip based restriction. We currently use this and it works fine. Just set an elastic ip on your ec2 instance (if you haven't already) and set the ip address in the access policy like this:

```
"Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
          ]
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else stumbling across this, here's a few things I learnt whilst I was stuck on something similar:

EC2's role ARN can be added in the access policy for your Elasticsearch domain along with the permissions you want the role to have. For eg. for an EC2 running with role "aws-ec2" needing permissions to make HTTP GET requests to ES, you could have the following in your ES domain access policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:role/aws-ec2",
        ]
      },
      "Action": "es:ESHttpGet",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT_ID>:domain/<DOMAIN_NAME>/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any requests made by an EC2 instance running with role "aws-ec2" in your account will have access to elasticsearch.

Note that if you have trouble getting credentials, try the following:

```
AWS.config.getCredentials(function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err.stack);
        // credentials not loaded
    else {
        // credentials are loaded and can be accessed using 
        AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId, AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKeyId etc. 
  }
});
```

This will usually pull the credentials in like magic, I have a theory about how it works (tl:dr; I think it pulls them from the EC2 instance metadata by making a request to a fixed IP) but it's unproven so I won't embarrass myself until I know more. Note that this should work even if you don't have credentials stored in your environment or in the shared credentials file.